# Regular expression String replacement.

Tags: regex, replace, ms-word

I have the following lines:

```
d:\Projects\qqq\Development\qqq.MySol1.sln  
d:\Projects\qqq\qqqDevelopment\qqqMySol2.sln  
d:\Projects\qqq\Development\MyInstaller.sln  
d:\Projects\qqq\qqq\Development\MyInstaller.sln  
d:\Projects\Development\MyInstaller.sln
```

I need an regular expression that will result in name captures:

```
Line 1: Development and MySol1.sln  
Line 2: Development and MySol2.sln  
Line 3: Development and MyInstaller.sln  
Line 4: Development and MyInstaller.sln  
Line 5: Development and MyInstaller.sln
```

So a regex that will remove (ignore) the word `qqq` from the lines.
I've been trying with The Regulator, and have a partial solution:

```
.*\\(?<A>.*)\\.{3}(?<B>.*)
```

This results in:

```
Line 1: Development and .MySol1.sln  
Line 2: qqqDevelopment and MySol2.sln  
Line 3: Development and nstaller.sln  
Line 4: Development and nstaller.sln  
Line 5: Development and nstaller.sln
```

So the `.{3}`  should be fixed somehow.

Comment: any particular language?

Comment: Is it always `qqq` or three times the same letter or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that should work:

```
.*\\(?:qqq)?(?<A>.*)\\(?:qqq)?(?<B>.*)
```